# pandas how to assign column name when aggregate same column

Tags: pandas, aggregate

Following command returns a df contains only 'website_id' and 'ctr':'var' 2 column. How can I return df contains all 4 columns with appropriate column name?

```
df.groupby(['website_id']).agg({'ctr':'count','ctr':'mean', 'ctr':'var'}
```

Comment: What does your input data frame look like and waht are your expected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to work with a sample df and expected output but I think you need

```
df.groupby(['website_id']).agg(['count','mean', 'var'])
```